# Phonegap IOS Running HiWorld Sample App Produces "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"

Tags: xcode4, cordova, ios4

OSX: 10.6.8
Xcode: 4.0.2
Phonegap: 1.4.1.js or Cardova-1.7.0

Following simple HiWorld example http://phonegap.com/start produces the following error from:

AppDelegate.m:

```
self.viewCOntroller = [[[MainViewCOntroller alloc] init] autorelease];
```

ERROR:

```
Thread 1: Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"
```

**EDIT**: I was using the ipad 3.2 Simulator, as soon as I changed it to iphone 4.0 or above the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

This is (in my opinion), the most common error in iOs development.

The error means that you're trying to access something that has already been released.

You may be trying to access the `viewController` sometime after having already released it.

Remove `autorelease` and see what happens.

Comment: First, thanks for responding.  I'm not at all familiar with ios just trying to do something with ios via phonegap and javascript.  When you say Remove autorelease, do you mean that attribute, the entire line, etc?